# Can I make mailR or RDCOMClient work with R 3.6.3?

Tags: r, email

I have R Version 3.6.3 and it seems mailR and RDCOMClient are not compatible with this version. Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: I've rephrased your title, as your version will very quickly lead to this question being closed (since package recommendations are off-topic here).

Comment: Thanks for the rephrase, hopefully that works.

Comment: I am using RDOMClient with R 3.6.3 at my job. You can try installing Rtools and recompile RDOMClient from the source code.